# laravel ajax pagination with bootstrap 4

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, pagination

This is a very basic question and there are too many solutions.

The most solutions are talking about making a jQuery `.pagination a` listener and make ajax call and display the results. so simple.

Consider the following scenario:

1. The user get the index page which contains the pagination
2. The pagination links are generated using `$paginator->links()`
3. Now the current page is 1 and the paginator links show page 1 as active
4. The user wants to go to page number 2 so he clicked number 2 in the pagination links
5. The Ajax works fine and we load data successfully
6. Now the user wants to return page number 1 (here is the problem). Because when the index page loaded in step 1 the: the current page is 1 and **bootstrap 4 do not generate Anchor tag "a" for the current page** and the jQuery '.pagination a' will not fire.

In bootstrap 4 the active page in pagination looks like the following: (no link no a tag)

```
<li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
   <span class="page-link">1</span>
</li>
```

Comment: When you load the data in step 5 does that include the pagination links? Do you update the pagination links anywhere (set active page to 2, unset active page for page1 and create a link to page1)?

Comment: yes. you are right. so we need a comprehensive example. I solved the problem temporarily by rendering the paginator in controller and returned it along side the result. hehehehe.

Comment: I posted the question to be a helpful example for others. and I will post my answer too as soon as I finish it.